# Converting Type to interface returns null reference

Tags: c#

I have the following interface

```
public interface IService
{
}
```

I also have some services which implement this interface under the namespace "Myapp.Services".

I'm getting all types in that namespace:

```
var Services = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where
                (t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, "Myapp.Services", StringComparison.Ordinal))
```

This is fine but I'm trying to cast those types to `IService[]`:

```
ar Services = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where
                    (t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, "Myapp.Services", StringComparison.Ordinal)) as IService[];
```

Somehow I'm getting a null reference.

How can I convert those types to `IService[]`?

Comment: have you tried `.ToArray<IService>()` ?

Comment: Type cannot ever be converted to your own interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i didn't find any Answer to my question neither by gooling or by trying something like Serializing the type since its `[Serializable]` and Dezialize it to the interface type .

what i wanted is to get all available services for a specific user so i needed a way to get all default services before filtring it .

in the end i went to the typical way which is something like :

```
        IList<IService> Services = new List<IService>();
        foreach(var service in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where
        (t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, "Myapp.Services", StringComparison.Ordinal) && t.BaseType == typeof(object)))
        {
            if (service.Name == nameof(GetAccountService))
            {
                Services.Add(new GetAccountService());
            }
            if (service.Name == nameof(GetCardsService))
            {
                Services.Add(new GetCardsService());
            }
        }
        return Services.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

A `Type` will *never* implement a user-defined interface. You can't cast an instance of `Type` to an interface. The object you would want to be casting is an instance of this particular type, not the `Type` object that represents its metadata.

What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

As another answer [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48581931/5789864), your query can never return run-time objects and Type-class never implements your own interfaces.

If the need is to get types deriving IService, then this is the way to get all classes which derives IService:

```
var Services = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(IService).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.IsClass).ToArray();
```

Please note: this query returns only classes. If you want Type for ISevice-interface also, then remove `&& t.IsClass`- condition.

After getting Types, you can create runtime-objects by calling [Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you have also run-time objects deriving IService.

Comment: this will return an Ienumerable of Type